# Svg sprite + CSS + Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I have this html page (http://oscarotero.com/svg/) with some svg icons loaded from external files using `<use xlink:href=""/>`.

I have also some css in the header to set the styles in the svg. (The strokes colors and width).

This works fine in firefox but in chrome the css is not applied if the xlink:href is targeted to an exernal file, only if the svg code in embed in the html.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: I think this is a known Firefox bug. Basically you should not be able style `<use>` differently, if you want that, clone it.

Comment: I don't want to style `<use>` differently, I just want style it. Chrome does not style `<use xlink:href="external.svg#id"/>` but it does with `<use xlink:href="#id"/>`

Comment: So you should include the css in the external svg file. Have to admit [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) aren't clear about that.

Comment: + Webkit browser have other bug while CSS animating a referenced element, cloned via `<use>` http://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/lshrp

Comment: why don't you use the object tag to include the svg?

Comment: Because I'd like to change the svg appearance using css (color, stroke width, etc), and to do this, only inline svg is allowed.